# How to create a gradle project which combines dependencies in one jar?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, shadowjar

I'm trying to create a gradle project which combines some dependencies in one single obfuscated jar (for now, I don't care about the obfuscated part). These dependencies are other gradle projects, defined in settings.gradle.

**My project does not contain any code directly.**

I'm trying to use the shadowJar plugin to generate a "fat" jar containing the dependencies. **I want this jar to be the default output jar of the project (replace the jar task ?).**

The goal is to be able to add this combined project as dependency of other projects using `compile project(:'MyCombinedProject')` which would add the generated fat jar as dependency.

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    /* Here I want to replace the jar task with the shadowjar */
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':MyProject1')
    compile project(':MyProject2')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

My projects paths are defined in `settings.gradle`.

Comment: One way to do this is to use `from ziptree(...)` in your jar task, instead of using the shadow plugin.

Comment: Why do you need a fatjar to use this project as a dependency? Shouldn't you be using transitive dependencies to propagate this project's dependencies?